presto sql get string of elements to get first and second items
Have a table which has a column of string type and the data looks like
items
['apple','pear','orange']
['weather','news']
.....

How could I get the first and second items as separated columns
expected output
first_item     second_item
apple          pear
weather        news

tried to cast column as array then slice it but failed
cast(itmes as array(varchar))

got  Cannot cast varchar to array(varchar)
Any suggestions?

SQL tables are set based, and represent unordered sets of records.  If you want a certain order in the output, then there need to be one or more columns which provide this perceived ordering.

Depending on actual data you can try treating it as JSON:
-- sample data
WITH dataset(items) AS (
   values ('["apple","pear","orange"]'),
    ('["weather","news"]')
)

-- query
select cast(json_parse(items) as array(varchar))[1] first_item, -- element_at
       cast(json_parse(items) as array(varchar))[2] second_item -- element_at
from dataset;

Output:



first_item
second_item




apple
pear


weather
news



Or just:
-- query
select json_extract_scalar(items, '$[0]') first_item,
       json_extract_scalar(items, '$[1]') second_item
from dataset;

